# Error no se carga el datable con los datos

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, datatables, datatable

Amigos, estoy tratando de integrar *datatables* en mi proyecto con el siguiente código.

**Controller**

```
use Yajra\DataTables\DataTables;
class varController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $var = Var::select(['id']);
 
        return Datatables::of($var)->make(true);
    }
}
```

**Ruta**

```
Route::resource('variab/var','VarController');
```

**Vista**

```
@extends ('layouts.var')
@section ('content')
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <title>Laravel DataTables</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/plugin/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/plugin/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="js/libs/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugin/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugin/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <table id="appointment-datatable" class="table table-hover table-condensed">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
@endsection 
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        oTable = $('#appointment-datatable').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": "{{ route('appointments') }}",
            "columns": [
                {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Resultados**

> "draw":0,"recordsTotal":167,"recordsFiltered":167,"data":[{"id":25},{"id":17},{"id":47},{"ida":122},{"id":114},{"id":40},{"id":110},{"id":134},{"id":135},{"id":27},{"id":21},{"id":133},{"id":150},
> count_row_table","bindings":[],"time":"1"},{"query":"select `var` from
> `vari`","bindings":[],"time":"1"}],"input":[]}

Composer.json

```
"require": {
    "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "~9.0"
},
```

Pero no salen dentro del marco los resultados ni dentro de la tabla. ¿Cómo haría para que me tome la datatable?
Gracias de antemano por la ayuda que pudieran brindarme.

Answer (score 0):

Estoy viendo a simple vista tenes un error en el id de la etiqueta table `#t#appointment-datatable`

```
@endsection 
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
    oTable = $('#appointment-datatable').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "{{ route('appointments') }}",
        "columns": [
            {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
        ]
     });
   });
 </script>
```

Que error te esta mostrando?

Comment: Gracias, por tus comentarios el error que tengo es que no imprime la vista solo esos esos resultados que muestro en el código es decir; los id pero no dentro de la tabla ni con los datos de la vista